# Docker container initially Exited

Tags: docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# comment
FROM sonatype/nexus3
COPY ./script.sh /bin/
CMD ["echo", "Image has been created!"]
```

Then I build image:

```
docker build -t test:latest ./
```

And run container:

```
docker run -d --name testcontainer test:latest
```

When I want to see list of all containers it shows me:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
4d7510a5938b        test:latest         "echo 'Image has bee..."   2 seconds ago       Exited (0) 1 second ago                       testcontainer
```

Why it is Exited state after run? What is interesting, when I comment line:

`#CMD ["echo", "Image has been created!"]`

Its starts without any problems - why?

Comment: If you do the thing CMD says by hand – `docker run test:latest echo 'Image has been created!'` – what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Print given message in console when "docker build" is perfomed

Comment: Aha.  That's what RUN would do, not CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'CMD' instructs Docker to make the argument(s) the default command that your container will execute when ran. It doesn't display anything during build.

The command that you gave in CMD does what you asked when you run the container - and exits immediately.

if you do not give a CMD in Dockerfile, then the CMD that was in the original image (FROM) will be used. That one probably runs something that stays in memory and doesn't exit - that's why it "works".

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers keep running until their command is finished or stopped.
having that in mind you can keep a container running forever with this command:

```
docker run -d ubuntu tail -F nothing
```

here we ask our container to show anything that was appended to file `nothing` which doesn't exist.
so this container will be running unless we stop it.
but the command you've set for your container is `echo something`, your container will stop after this command runs successfully.
if you execute this:

```
docker logs your_container_name
```

you will see that the container has echoed what you've asked for and then exited.
if you want your container to run forever replace this line:

```
CMD ["echo", "Image has been created!"]
```

with:

```
CMD ["tail", "-F", "nothing"]
```